# Socket.io with Express.js routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

I am using socketio with expressjs with its routes as a middleware. Below is my code. Currently, my setup is not working with my current approach. Below are the code snippets that I am using but none of the is working. How can make this work?

nodejs code here is index.js

```
let app = require('express')();
let http = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(http);

let newRoute = require('./routes/new');

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log('Listening to Socket');

    socket.on('FirstEvent', msg => {
        console.log(msg); // This works fine, no issues here and question is not for this.
    });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});

app.use('/new', newRoute);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

http.listen(port, function() {
console.log('listening in http://localhost:' + port);
});
```

here is new.js

```
let express = require('express');
let route = express.Router();

route.get('/', (request, response) => {
    console.log('NEW ROUTE'); // this is logs out.
    request.io.on('RouteEvent', msg => {
        console.log(msg); // this does not pop out
    });

    response.json({
        'RES': 'No Socket IO data'
    });
});

module.exports = route;
```

Here is my home.ts file with following code on front end side using ionic 3

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { RestServiceProvider } from '../../providers/rest-service/rest-service';

import { Socket } from 'ng-socket-io';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    nickname = '';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private socket: Socket, private rest: RestServiceProvider) { }

    joinChat() {
        this.socket.connect();
        this.socket.emit('FirstEvent', {
            'FirstEvent': 'AN EVENT TRAGETTED TO index.js ON SERVER SIDE'
        });

        this.rest.get().subscribe(response => {
            console.log('A LOG AFTER CALLING REST GET FUNCTION'); // 

            console.log('RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER: ', response);

            this.socket.emit('RouteEvent', {
                'RouteEvent': 'AN EVENT SENT TO THE ROUTE ON SERVER SIDE'
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Here is my rest-service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
Generated class for the RestServiceProvider provider.

See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class RestServiceProvider {

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello RestServiceProvider Provider');
    }

    get() {
        console.log('GETTTTTT');
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/new');
    }

}
```

Where is the mistake I am making here?

---

THIS IS AN UPDATE

I am still waiting for the solution.

I also tried this following approach. I wrapped the route into a function and passed io as a parameter at the time of requiring in index.js file.

Here is my new.js file

```
let express = require('express');
let route = express.Router();

module.exports = (io) => {
    console.log(io);
    route.get('/', (request, response) => {
        console.log(io);

        io.on('RouteEvent', msg => {
            console.log(msg);
        });

        response.json({
            'RES': 'No Socket IO data'
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my index.js file

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let server = app.listen(3001);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);
let cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

let newRoute = require('./routes/new')(io); // this returns 404 not found

console.log('Server listening at port 3000');
```

The above approach returns the the route 404 not found when I make a request from client(which is the same as above). Then I added app.use() to newRoute which is below.

```
let newRoute = require('./routes/new')(io);
app.use('/new', newRoute);
```

Then it started returning below error.

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

Any idea where am I doing it wrong and the solution?

Comment: When you say "none of it is working", can you be a bit more specific please? Where does it appear to be breaking?

Comment: It does not break but I am not receiving any event at all on the server side in route mentioned above.

Comment: Anyone who can help? I am still waiting for the solution for this one.

Comment: In `new.js`, try wrapping your events in `request.io.on('connection', (socket) => {` - everything in socket.io needs to be wrapped in connection handlers.

Comment: That didnt work either. In indexjs I do receive events from client but not in routes file.

Comment: Look at this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file

Comment: I already used that solution as you can see in above question.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeError you're getting in your updated solution is because in `new.js`, the function you're exporting is returning undefined (because there's no return statement).  If you return the route, your code should work:

```
const express = require('express');
const route = express.Router();

module.exports = (io) => {
    console.log(io);
    route.get('/', (request, response) => {
        console.log(io);

        io.on('RouteEvent', msg => {
            console.log(msg);
        });

        response.json({
            'RES': 'No Socket IO data'
        });
    });

    return route; // add this return statement
}
```