# how to get realtime data in nodejs mongodb and angularjs using SocketsJs?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sockets, websocket, real-time

i have a nodejs server which is getting list of a collection from mongodb . Here is its code . since am new to sockets so ..

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io');
```

after that iam simply getting data in a  route . and one thing more  all code is in one file and i do need  express route as there are other routes in app.   here is the mongodb code for getting list

```
app.post("/getAllOfferManagement",
    async (req, res) => {
        try {
            MongoClient.connect(url,
                function(err, db) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var dbo = db.db("realtime");
                    dbo
                        .collection("offer")
                        .find({})
                        .toArray(function(err,
                            result) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            // console.log('getting it ');
                            res.send(result);
                            db.close();
                        });
                });
        } catch (err) {
            res.send("error");
        }
    }); // its all working fine when i hit the route

http.listen(5000, function() {
    console.log("Server Started!");
});
//serversidecode ends here
```

Now am getting the data through angular and here is the code for it

```
$scope.getAllOffer = function() {

    $scope.mongoloader = true;

    //nodejs api endpoint 
    $http.post("http://localhost:5000/getAllOffer").then(function(res) {
        $scope.offersArray = res.data;
        console.log('data here', res.data);
    });
};
```

the above works fine .  but i need to get data in realtime e.g  when somone insert new doc in mongodb  the the view get updates . am new to sockets so any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this u have to add an event to backend and as well as in frontend 
Backend

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    console.log(socket.id);


    socket.on('SEND_TITLE', function(data){

        io.emit('RECEIVE_TITLE', data);

        console.log('data',data)

    })

});
```

For frontend u have to use socket io client module

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
socket = io('your backend host url')

    socket.on('RECEIVE_TITLE', function(data)
      Console. Log(data);

  });
```

Frontend syntax could differ in angular. 
As I am not familiar with angular

For more information visit.

Forclient side.

https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

For server.

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

Comment: well  thanks for reply .  But  i have an api  route .  I need to use socket only on  that  api endpoint .  I dont know  how to use sockets inside  express route

Comment: I think this would help you.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837685/use-socket-io-in-expressjs-routes-instead-of-in-main-server-js-file]