# Socket double emits problem in express route (event handler stacking)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes

I have problem with stacking socket event handler when hitting express route. I need to reconnect in route then sending emit to specific room.

At first I connect (socket.io) at page X, then connection is lost cause I move to page Y (with use of router.post) and then in router when I reconnect I add new global socket.io handler for the connection event... and cause of that emits are send multiple times.

Ideally, I should use some kind of session to know that user disconnect/connect and be able to recognize him (sending emits to specific room).

**INDEX.JS** file (main "app" file):

```
var x = require('./routes/x.js');
var app = express();
app.use('/', x);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
    next();
});
var server = http.createServer(options, app).listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log('Server started!');
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

// here we also set rules for socket.io connection:
io.on('connection', function (soc) {
    soc.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });
    // soc.on('reconnect', ... etc.
});
```

route in **X.JS** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.post('/Y', function(req, res, next) {
    request(opt, function(err, resp, body) {
        if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
            res.render('Y'); // so the emits can target something (later they build html structure on page 'Y' with proper data, but there must be some structure first)

            function socCon() {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                // so in a route when socket is disconnected and need to be connect again (cause you change location - path) you do it here and it duplicate (just as you said) event handler EVERY time that route is hit:
                    req.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
                        var room = 'room_' + socket.id;
                        socket.join(room);

                        if (socket.join(room)) {
                            resolve(room);
                        }
                        else {
                            reject(console.log('error'));
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            socCon().then(data).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            function data(room) {
                req.io.in(room).emit('msg', {emit : 'message'}); // socket.io emits - with use of express route POST on page 'X'
            });
        }
        else {
            res.render('X', {ERRORS : ERRORS});
            res.end(); // do res.end() is needed... after res.render() I guess no...
        }
    });
)};
module.exports = router;
```

Client page **Y**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected!');
    });
    socket.on('msg', function(msg) {
        // some HTML mutation here that happened MULTIPLE times causing errors (cause same emit is emitted multiple times)
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You aren't exporting anything from `x.js` so `app.use('/', x);` won't do anything.

Comment: You cannot ever add an event handler like this `req.io.on('connection', ...)` inside a route definition because (as you've seen, they will just pile up with lots of duplicates).  That is not ever how you program for socket.io events.  Those type of event handlers go at the top level for all routes - you can't have one that is route-specific.  Also, this event handler catches all new connection events from all clients, not even just from this client.

Comment: My mistake, I have forgot about exporting router. I need to make a socket.io connection in a route - how to do that? How I can connect with a user inside a route and then make some emits?

Comment: Well, you can't emit from a route handler that renders the page.  It's too soon.  The browser hasn't received the new page, parsed it, run the Javascript and let the page connect.  If you want to send the user some data at page render time, then you should put the data in the page you send them (that's what template engines are used for).  I think you'll have to edit your question to explain what problem you're really trying to solve here so someone can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: It is working (it's wrong design I know - but it is working - page is rendered then socket connection is established). I could use promise or async/await to render the page first, and then do socket connection it's not a problem (I think). But I still stacking socket event handler when hitting express route. Question is - how I can connect in a route - without stacking socket 'connection' event handler? If I remove socket io 'connection' event from index.js file (app) and I will set it inside routes it will still send multiple emits... I cant find a solution...

Comment: Please read the last sentence of my previous comment.  When you've edited your question to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish, then maybe we could offer solutions.  This is not the right approach.  This cannot work reliably.